# Rails belongs_to vs parent_id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Generic active record questions:
- Advantages/disadvantages of belongs_to association vs a parent_id column?
- Conventions regarding the 2?
- Does belongs_to association enforce `:null => false` ?

```
class CreateIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration

def change
  create_table :issues do |t|
    t.belongs_to :project

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

VS

```
class CreateIssues < ActiveRecord::Migration

def change
  create_table :issues do |t|
    t.integer :project_id, :null => false

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

belongs_to() is just an alias to references(), which does not enforce the (:null => false) condition.  Check out the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L421).

I find it's more common to use references(), but again, belongs_to() is a valid alias.

It's uncommon to see the reference written out manually, as its part of the way ActiveRecord simplifies these associations.